# Mutate subset average and add to all groups R

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I'm trying to create mean values for a certain subset of my data, and I want to add these as a new variable to a different subset of the data.

Say I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(year = rep(c(2010,2012,2017), 6),
                 party = rep(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 2),
                 left = rep(c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1),2),
                 area = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                 pp = c(3,4,5,1,2,6,3,4,2,5,1,1,3,4,5,2,3,0))
```

Which looks like:

```
year party left area pp
2010     A    1    1  3
2012     A    1    1  4
2017     A    1    1  5
2010     B    0    1  1
2012     B    0    1  2
2017     B    0    1  6
2010     C    1    1  3
2012     C    1    1  4
2017     C    1    1  2
2010     A    1    2  5
2012     A    1    2  1
2017     A    1    2  1
2010     B    0    2  3
2012     B    0    2  4
2017     B    0    2  5
2010     C    1    2  2
2012     C    1    2  3
2017     C    1    2  0
```

Now what I want is to create a new variable within each "year" and "area" for left == 1, that is the average of "pp". But I also want to this to the subset where left == 0.

I tried:

```
df %>%
  group_by(year, left, area) %>%
  mutate(mean_left = mean(pp)) %>% ungroup()
```

But this gives me a value specific for left == 0 and a specific value for left == 1 (within each year,party).

```
year party  left  area    pp mean_left
<dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
2010 A         1     1     3       3  
2012 A         1     1     4       4  
2017 A         1     1     5       3.5
2010 B         0     1     1       1  
2012 B         0     1     2       2  
2017 B         0     1     6       6  
2010 C         1     1     3       3  
2012 C         1     1     4       4  
2017 C         1     1     2       3.5
2010 A         1     2     5       3.5
2012 A         1     2     1       2  
2017 A         1     2     1       0.5
2010 B         0     2     3       3  
2012 B         0     2     4       4  
2017 B         0     2     5       5  
2010 C         1     2     2       3.5
2012 C         1     2     3       2  
2017 C         1     2     0       0.5
```

I also tried:

```
df %>%
  group_by(year, left, area) %>%
  mutate(mean_left = mean(df$pp[df$left==1])) %>% ungroup()
```

But here the group_by function seems to fail and I get 2.75 in all columns (which is the value of `mean(df$pp[df$left==1])`)

How can I get a mean score per year & area for left == 1, adding this same number to this year & area for left == 2?

It should look like:

```
year party  left  area    pp mean_left
<dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
2010 A         1     1     3       3  
2012 A         1     1     4       4  
2017 A         1     1     5       3.5
2010 B         0     1     1       3  
2012 B         0     1     2       4  
2017 B         0     1     6       3.5  
2010 C         1     1     3       3  
2012 C         1     1     4       4  
2017 C         1     1     2       3.5
2010 A         1     2     5       3.5
2012 A         1     2     1       2  
2017 A         1     2     1       0.5
2010 B         0     2     3       3.5  
2012 B         0     2     4       2  
2017 B         0     2     5       0.5  
2010 C         1     2     2       3.5
2012 C         1     2     3       2  
2017 C         1     2     0       0.5
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track; you must not group_by `left` but select it within your mean function.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(year, area) %>%
  mutate(mean_left = mean(pp[left == 1])) %>%
  ungroup()
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 18 x 6
    year party  left  area    pp mean_left
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1  2010 A         1     1     3       3  
 2  2012 A         1     1     4       4  
 3  2017 A         1     1     5       3.5
 4  2010 B         0     1     1       3  
 5  2012 B         0     1     2       4  
 6  2017 B         0     1     6       3.5
 7  2010 C         1     1     3       3  
 8  2012 C         1     1     4       4  
 9  2017 C         1     1     2       3.5
10  2010 A         1     2     5       3.5
11  2012 A         1     2     1       2  
12  2017 A         1     2     1       0.5
13  2010 B         0     2     3       3.5
14  2012 B         0     2     4       2  
15  2017 B         0     2     5       0.5
16  2010 C         1     2     2       3.5
17  2012 C         1     2     3       2  
18  2017 C         1     2     0       0.5
```